# WPF ItemsControl: Change ItemsSource of ItemsControl from Current Selection of another ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl that contains product categories and I have another ItemsControl that contains a list of all the articles catégoie currently selected, I need to related the current selection of the category with the binding of the ItemsControl articles

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categories}">
...
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
          <Button Content="{Binding Path=CategorieCaption}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
...
</ItemsControl>


<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedCategories.Articles}">
...
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
          <Button Content="{Binding Path=ArticleCaption}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
...
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: How would you actually select items in an ItemsControl? You should perhaps use a ListBox instead.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your data bound `Article` collection each time the `Category` is changed. If you add a property to data bind with the `ListBox.SelectedItem`, then you can do that from the property setter:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}" ... />
```

..

```
public Category SelectedCategory
{
    get { return selectedCategory; }
    set
    {
        if (selectedCategory != value)
        {
            selectedCategory = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedCategory");
            // Selected Category was changed, so update Articles collection
            Articles = UpdateArticlesByCategory(selectedCategory);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that there is no `SelectedItem` property in ItemsControl :-)

Comment: hi @Sheridan,the ItemsControl **can't** select items, only present collections

Comment: Then use a `ListBox`.

Comment: Thanks once again... what would I do without you, @Clemens? I've updated my answer accordingly.